# How to Resolve the 'Value of type 'AppDelegate' has no member 'navigationController' ' issue for the 'SideMenu' CocoaPod?

Tags: ios, swift, swift5, side-menu

I am using the 'SideMenu' Cocoapod, and I copy and pasted the code to add view controllers in my AppDelegate.swift as it says to, and it's all good except the addPanGesture and addScreenEdgePanGesture. Here's my code for my entire AppDelegate.swift:

```
import UIKit
import SideMenu
    
@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
        // Define the menus
        let leftMenuNavigationController = SideMenuNavigationController(rootViewController: UIViewController())
        SideMenuManager.default.leftMenuNavigationController = leftMenuNavigationController

        let rightMenuNavigationController = SideMenuNavigationController(rootViewController: UIViewController())
        SideMenuManager.default.rightMenuNavigationController = rightMenuNavigationController

        // Setup gestures: the left and/or right menus must be set up (above) for these to work.
        // Note that these continue to work on the Navigation Controller independent of the view controller it displays!
        SideMenuManager.default.addPanGestureToPresent(toView:
            self.navigationController.navigationBar)
        SideMenuManager.default.addScreenEdgePanGesturesToPresent(toView: self.navigationController.view)


        // (Optional) Prevent status bar area from turning black when menu appears:
        leftMenuNavigationController.statusBarEndAlpha = 0
        // Copy all settings to the other menu
        rightMenuNavigationController.settings = leftMenuNavigationController.settings
    }

    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

    // If you need your SideMenu to appear from the right side
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    
        
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    }
}
```

If anyone knows what I need to add to make these issues go away please let me know!

Comment: Your `AppDelegate` does not define a `navigationController`. You can either use your `UIWindow` instance to get the reference to the `UINAvigationController` from the root `UIViewController` or move this logic to your root `UIViewController`. I suggest that you take a look at the example project (in this project the author did not initialize the SideMenu in the AppDelegate): https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu/tree/master/Example